# Console hosted WCF data service with transport security running but not found by clients

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, odata

I have a WCF data service self hosted in a console application. It runs without complains and when security is set to "None" it works like a charm.
Now, when I enable transport security, it still runs, but when I hit the url in the web browser it doesn't find it. I'm using a self signed certificate to test it.

I would appreciate any help and advice.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer> 

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
          <!--<security mode="None"/>-->
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleServiceHost.BooksDataService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8900" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="BooksDataService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler"></endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SSLBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="a3 6f 22 85 86 09 f0 4b 12 3c ea 18 10 c7 14 63 32 f8 a0 6e" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            <defaultPorts>
              <add scheme="https" port="443"/>
            </defaultPorts>
          </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>  
  </system.serviceModel>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Here is my service code:

```
public class BooksDataService : DataService<SampleDbEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

And here is the code to host it:

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(BooksDataService), new Uri[0]);

    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine(host.BaseAddresses[0]);
    Console.ReadKey();

    host.Close();
}
```

Comment: What _exactly_ happens when you visit the service URL in your browser?

Comment: I hit the service url: https://localhost:8900/BooksDataService, then the browser shows the "Web site not found message".

Comment: Yeah that's not exact enough. Disable IE's "User friendly error pages". Do you get a response from IIS? What is the exact response?

Comment: Done. Still shows the same, with no details. Tested in chrome and edge too.

Comment: In chrome it shows in the devtools "Failed to load response data".

Comment: Even tracked the network traffic to loopback interface with Wireshark, adding the corresponding route of course. I get traffic when security is set to "None" and I get nothing when is set to "Transport" and https. I filtered ports 8900 and 443.

Comment: Try to enable WCF and System.Net tracing to find out what's going on under the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I hadn't attach the certificate to the application port. I missed this command:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8900 appid={cc57b9c6bbd7-468d-81be-779e6a74099e} certhash=a36f22858609f04b123cea1810c7146332f8a06e
```

Thanks to this post answered by [Hasan Baidoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853025/hasan-baidoon): 
[WCF DataService over Https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397614/wcf-dataservice-over-https).

Thank you [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) for your colaboration.